# Classe não injeta na outra (Injeção de Dependência)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express.js, mongoose

Estou aprendendo sobre injeção de dependência desenvolvendo uma API, mas estou com um problema que não consigo arrumar.

Basicamente o problema é que uma classe injeta normalmente em uma, mas por algum motivo não injeta na outra, segue o código:

MongooseUserRepository

```
const UserMongooseModel = mongoose.model('user', new Schema<IUser>({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    confirm_password: { type: String, required: true }
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
));

export class MongooseUserRepository implements IUserRepository {
    async findByUsername(username: string): Promise<IUser> {

        const userAlreadyExists = await UserMongooseModel.findOne({ username }) as mongoose.Document & IUser;

        return userAlreadyExists;
    }

    async create(data: ICreateUserRequest): Promise<IUser> {
        if (data.password !== data.confirm_password) {
            throw new BadRequestAPIError('As senhas não coincidem !');
        }

        const newUser = new UserMongooseModel(data);
        const saveUser = newUser.save();

        return saveUser;
    }
}
```

CreateUserUseCase

```
export class CreateUserUseCase implements IUseCase {
    constructor(
        private readonly createUserRepository: IUserRepository
    ) { }

    async execute(data: ICreateUserRequest): Promise<IUser> {
        const userAlreadyExists = await this.createUserRepository.findByUsername(data.username);

        if (userAlreadyExists) {
            throw new BadRequestAPIError('Já existe um usuário registrado com esse username !');
        }

        const newUser = this.createUserRepository.create(data);

        return newUser;
    }
}
```

CreateUserController

```
export class CreateUserController implements IController {
    constructor(
        private readonly createUserUseCase: IUseCase
    ) { }

    async handle(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
        const { username, password, confirm_password }: IUser = req.body;

        const newUser = await this.createUserUseCase.execute({
            username,
            password,
            confirm_password
        });

        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Conta criada com sucesso !',
            newUser
        });
    }
};
```

createUserFactory

```
const makeCreateUserFactory = (): CreateUserController => {
    const mongooseUserRepository = new MongooseUserRepository();
    const createUserUseCase = new CreateUserUseCase(mongooseUserRepository);
    const createUserController = new CreateUserController(createUserUseCase);

    return createUserController;
};

export const createUserController = makeCreateUserFactory();
```

O principal erro que eu pude notar usando console.log() foi que o Repository consegue se injetar no UseCase, mas por algum motivo o UseCase NÃO consegue se injetar no Controller, porque utilizando o console.log() no construtor dessas classes com .this o construtor do Controller retorna undefined, enquanto o do UseCase retorna a sua classe injetada normalmente (Repository):

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

> Constructor CreateUserController: undefined

> Constructor CreateUserUseCase MongooseUserRepository {}

Já tentei de todas as formas consertar isso, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, eu não estava passando os parâmetros necessários para o Controller na rota, porque sem injeção de dependência é assim que eu fazia

Errado

```
authRoute.post('/auth/register', createUserController.handle);
```

Certo

```
authRoute.post('/auth/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    await createUserController.handle(req, res);
});
```